# I need an alernative to "before" and "after", which alphabetize with after after before

Tags: vocabulary, alphabet

Some software I use likes to alphabetize things, so I'd like an alternative to before and after, where sorting lexicographical is the same as sorting by time.

Comment: Prior and subsequent, before and later

Comment: Make it an answer and I'll mark it as accepted ;)

Comment: Spanish offers *antes* for before and *después* for after. :-):-) :-)

Comment: I find "before" and "after" natural in such contexts (but dislike greater than and less than). Might "earlier" and "later" be any better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ante and post, from Latin, which are represented verbatim in a.m. and p.m. and can also be used as prefixes in English words.